# Android ImageView - How to not make imageview tinted

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have the following `layout.xml`:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

I set the background color of the parent `LinearLayout` like this:

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#727272"));
    layout.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

However, the `ImageView` (id:image) is tinted. Is there a way not to tint the `ImageView` while setting the background color of its parent layout?

Comment: what is eventLogoLayout?

Comment: why do you set eventLogoLayout.setAlpha(0.5f)? It's tinted maybe depend on your logo. You have to attach your screenshoot here.

Comment: set ImageView background = null. may be it's help you

Comment: @Mark Shen, it is layout. Updated.

Comment: @Konstantin, i don't understand what you mean to set ImageView background = null because I have to set the image for the imageView. I tried to set android:background="@color/transparent" in the imageView, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ikhsan, setAlpha(0.5f) is kind of requirement and image is tinted because of it.

Comment: @Huigege, I mean: android:src="@drawable/your_image" - set src of image, android:background="@null" - set imageview backgound null

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the image is tinted because I call the setAlpha for the parent layout:

```
layout.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

However, it is required for me to set the 50% opacity for the parent layout. So I use the below way to set Alpha and RGB for the background color of parent layout and it works: background color of the parent layout is set without tinting the child's image.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setBackgroundColor(BitmapDrawableUtility. getColorByOpacityPercentage(calculateOpacity(Color.parseColor("#727272"), 50));


public static int getColorByOpacityPercentage(int color, double percentage) {
    int transparency = (int) Math.round((percentage / 100.0) * 255.0);
    return Color.argb(transparency, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
}
```