# Why does the parent's background affect the child views' color?

Tags: android, background

My setup is a `LinearLayout` that contains either an `AppCompatImageView` in which I display a vector drawable or a `TextView` in which I show an emoji. I set the `background` of the layout via xml to `android:background="#FF0000"` which makes it appear red. The problem is both the displayed icon and the emoji are tinted red now. The image below shows two instances of this (two times the parent layout, once with the `ImageView` and once with the `TextView`).

[image: tinted ImageView and TextView]

The xml that produces this (ok, almost, but the problem is there):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_width="24dp"
      android:layout_height="24dp"
      android:background="#FF0000">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_width="24dp"
      android:layout_height="24dp"
      android:background="#FF0000">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_backspace_24"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801784/android-imageview-how-to-not-make-imageview-tinted#) which has the exact same symptom as I observed. However, it seems there is an alpha problem, which I don't have. All alpha values in my case are `1.0f`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638193/changing-the-background-color-affects-children) which asks about `background` being set through the theme affecting all the child views. But since it seems to change the background color of the child views, I am not sure this has anything to do with my problem.

I tried (without results):

- setting the `background` of the image view to `null`
- using a `FrameLayout` as parent
- setting the background color programmatically
- setting `textView.setTextColor(R.color.black)` with `black` being `#FF000000`

(The actual problem I tried to solve is a "white fog" on my icons. Testing with red revealed that the icons would be tinted by the background, so I suspect that whatever causes the red tint also caused the initial "white fog" I was seeing.)

What causes this? How do I avoid it?

Comment: Could you post the XML code of the layout?

Comment: I added the xml as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has different aspects. As [Steven Meliopoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65982184) pointed out, the core reason is that both the emoji and the drawable have an alpha component to their color.

**The Drawable**

From the code of the drawable it is apparent that it is colored with `?attr/colorControlNormal`:

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="24dp"
  android:height="24dp"
  android:viewportWidth="24"
  android:viewportHeight="24"
  android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M22,3L7,3c-0.69,0 -1.23,0.35 -1.59,0.88L0,12l5.41,8.11c0.36,0.53 0.9,0.89 1.59,0.89h15c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L24,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM19,15.59L17.59,17 14,13.41 10.41,17 9,15.59 12.59,12 9,8.41 10.41,7 14,10.59 17.59,7 19,8.41 15.41,12 19,15.59z"/>
</vector>
```

This color is defined to be `?android:attr/textColorSecondary` in the theme that I am using. The theme is the default for new apps (at least when I created my project): `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. It seems that this color is defined by the device, but I am not sure about this. At least on the emulator this color has an alpha component. So changing the `tint` to `android:tint="#FF000000"` makes the icon black regardless of the background color.

**The Emoji**

Further testing revealed that the emoji is colored with `android:textColorTertiary`, which is (in my theme) only used in `Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small#android:textColor`. I have no idea how that is linked with a `TextView`'s text color, but at least I know how to change it:

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"))
```

or in `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:textColorTertiary">#FF000000</item>
```

This makes the emoji opaque as the color's alpha channel is at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue with the TextView. It seems to happen because the text color from the default theme has an alpha component that is less than 100%, which then also gets applied to emojis. So the "tint" can be avoided by assigning any text color with 100% alpha (or no alpha component).

For the ImageView I suspect is has to do with the drawable resource itself. If your backspace icon is a vector drawable you could also add the code to your post or check its fill color value.

Comment: Could you please post the code that made it work for you? How do you set the color with 100% alpha? (I'll edit my question to include what I tried in that regard)

Comment: @notihs, the first two digits are the alpha channel, not the last. Also, the background is not the problem - the foreground is. But I just figured out that using `textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"))` works.

Comment: Even just #000000 should work as well. If the alpha component is omitted it will default to  FF/100%.

Comment: removed my comment since it had a lot of incorrect info. sorry about that